# Filter interpolation issues

Tags: angularjs

I am stuck with an AngularJS filter issue and would appreciate an advise. In several different views I have numbers, like 1000000000, which are hard to read. Task is to separate each three digits' block by commas. To do that I have written a filter:

```
angular.module('AppCore')
.filter('numberCommaSeparator', function () {
    return function (x) {
        x = x.toString();
        var pattern = /(-?\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (pattern.test(x))
            x = x.replace(pattern, "$1,$2");

        return x;
    }
});
```

Added the filter in the view:

```
<span ng-if="project.value != 0">{{project.currency.name}} {{project.value|numberCommaSeparator}}</span>
<span ng-if="project.value == 0">N/A</span>
```

In two places out of three it works flawlessly, however, in the third case I do constantly receive a mistake:

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{project.currency.name}} {{project.value|numberCommaSeparator}}
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show the input data? Error clearly says that in some case your `project.value` is undefined

Comment: There are cases when it could be undefined, but in this case ng-if will throw N/A. And the point is that the filter works in spite of the error - I do get "UK Pound 68,850,000" in my view instead of "UK Pound 68850000". Re input data - this particular mistake appears while trying to amend 68850000

Comment: But if the value is *undefined*, the first ng-if condition `project.value != 0` is satisfied, not the second, you should check also for undefined to avoid that

Comment: @m.belica Indeed! My bad :) After changing the ng-if condition in the view from project.value != 0 to project.value > 0 the error disappeared. I will check what's there behind the error, but still, great that it works. Answer the question so that I could mark your answer as approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that in some case your `project.value` is *undefined*

If that value is *undefined*, the first ng-if condition `project.value != 0` is satisfied, not the second, you should check also for undefined to avoid that error.